# Jenkins unable to build C#6 features until second execution

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a .Net application being built by Jenkins Pipelines and jenkinsfile. My Jenkins installation (up to date on the LTS versions) is unable to build my .Net application the first time within a workspace. Any new branch creates a new workspace then fails to build:

```
"<JENKINS_WORKSPACE_FOR_BRANCH\src\MY_SOLUTION.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"<JENKINS_WORKSPACE_FOR_BRANCH\src\Core\MySln.Core.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  Configuration\DefaultConfiguration.cs(143,51): error CS1002: ; expected [<JENKINS_WORKSPACE_FOR_BRANCH\src\Core\MySln.Core.csproj]
  Configuration\DefaultConfiguration.cs(143,54): error CS1520: Method must have a return type [<JENKINS_WORKSPACE_FOR_BRANCH\src\Core\MySln.Core.csproj]
  Configuration\DefaultConfiguration.cs(143,66): error CS1031: Type expected [<JENKINS_WORKSPACE_FOR_BRANCH\src\Core\MySln.Core.csproj]
  Model\User.cs(48,24): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [<JENKINS_WORKSPACE_FOR_BRANCH\src\Core\MySln.Core.csproj]
  Model\User.cs(75,20): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [<JENKINS_WORKSPACE_FOR_BRANCH\src\Core\MySln.Core.csproj]
```

Line 143 is

```
public string MyProperty=> ConfigValue("MyProperty");
```

Using the new C# 6 Expression Bodied Function Members syntax. The unexpected Character '$' is the c# 6 string formatting syntax:

```
var mystring = $"This is where I'll put {thisProperty} in my string";
```

My build call is:

```
bat "\"${tool 'MSBuildPipeline'}\" src\\MY_SOLUTION.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:PlatformTarget=x64 /p:ProductVersion=1.3.5.${env.BUILD_NUMBER} /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5 /ToolsVersion:12.0 /p:FrameworkOverride=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Reference Assemblies\\Microsoft\\Framework\\.NETFramework\\v4.5\""
```

Which used to be much simpler but I've been trying to specify more and more to get to the bottom of this. I'm using MSBuild 12. I attempted to use MSBuild 14 but there's a problem with building on MSBuild 14 where you need to install a Windows 10 SDK to enable license generation and the SDKs only exist for .Net versions 4.6.x. I've got the Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.3.2 NuGet packages installed to help enable the c# 6 syntax. The new 2.0.1 version only supports MSBuild 14.0+.

Again, it will only error out for the first build in this workspace. **If I hit build again it will succeed without issue**, despite no code changes. I'm assuming it's pulling some sort of .dll or asset the first time which fixes the issue for subsequent builds but I don't know what.

Comment: "I'm using MSBuild 12. " `C# 6` introduced in Visual Studio 2015, you need to update your `msbuild` and there is no any other way to compile `C# 6` with these version of Msbuild.

Comment: Have you looked on this article: http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/12/building-net-461-project-with-jenkins.html

Comment: But @AliBahraminezhad, it builds fine the second time, or for any other commits after the first which fails.

Comment: And as mentioned, using MSBuild 14 introduces a license generation error which can not be solved with .Net 4.5 short of hacky batch scripts to generate the license with an older version (thus depending on two installs to execute). Just upgrading to .Net 4.6.x might be an option but that involves updates across the entire deployment path.